# VBA CDO Sending old image in email body

Tags: vba, excel, cdo.message

I'm using vba to send email using CDO (See below) it keeps pulling a old image from over 30 days ago for the email that it is sending out.  Can anyone help?

```
Public Function sndmail(ByVal RecipientList As String, _
    ByVal Subject As String, ByVal body As String, Optional ByVal Attachment As String, _
    Optional ByVal cc As String)
Dim iMsg As Message
Dim iConf As Configuration
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "SMTP.xx.xyz.COM"
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
  .Update
End With

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = RecipientList
    .cc = cc
    .From = "chris@yoohoo.com"
    .Subject = Subject
    .HTMLBody = body
End With

iMsg.Send

End Function

...

imgfile = "C:\TEMP\FDW_Img.png"
imgfile2 = "C:\TEMP\FDW_DoD.png"
Set pp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = pp.Presentations.Open("C:\TEMP\bpp.pptx")
wbk1.Sheets("Summary by Modcode").Range("F22:Z28").Copy
ppt.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteBitmap)
ppt.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Export imgfile, ppShapeFormatPNG
ppt.Close
pp.Quit
DoEvents

'list of recipients
sndto = ""
'subject line for email
subj = "5 State Capital Finance Reports for  " & Date
'body of email
bod = "Happy " & WeekdayName(Weekday(Date)) & "! <br>" & WeekdayName(Weekday(Date)) & "'s reports have been updated and can be found at the below links and snapshots can be found at the first weblink:<br><br>" & _
 "<a href = a weblink here that currently works fine> Finance Website </a> <br>" & _
    "<a href = another one here... works fine> Open vs Actuals </a> <br>" & _
    "<a href = another one here... works fine> EE Report <a><br>" & _
    "<a href = another one here... works fine> FDW Actuals <a>" & _
    " <br> <br><img src='C:\Temp\FDW_img.png'><br><br>" & sig
'function to send email
sndmail sndto, subj, bod
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbk1.Close False
```

This line is where it adds the image to the body of the email and it is adding an old image... the strange thing is that on the host pc if I pull up my email it shows correctly but on all other recipients or if I pull up my email on another pc it shows up with the old image.

```
" <br> <br><img src='C:\Temp\FDW_img.png'><br><br>" & sig
```

Comment: Their browsers are possibly caching the image from the last time they received an email with that image link.  Do they have that same file and folder on their computers and is the file updated on them?  It looks like you are telling the html to open the image from their computers, but I've never worked with CDO to send mail.

Comment: well duh... thank you! I changed the path to a shared location and now it updates correctly.